# Sending data to a Dialog

Tags: android

While reading the documentation for DialogFragment in AndroidDevelopers

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

I came across the example for the BasicDialog that seemed odd. To pass data to the dialogFragment it uses a factory method that receives the data as argument and stores it in a bundle. Then, on the onCreate method, it 'unpacks' the data from the bundle and sets the private fields. Why they don't use the constructor to provide that data? Why is this dance necessary (or at least preferable)?

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
int mNum;

/**
 * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
 * as an argument.
 */
static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");

    // Pick a style based on the num.
    int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 1: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 2: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 3: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_INPUT; break;
        case 4: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        case 5: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        case 6: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 7: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 8: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
    }
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 4: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo; break;
        case 5: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog; break;
        case 6: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
        case 7: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel; break;
        case 8: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
    }
    setStyle(style, theme);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
    View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ((TextView)tv).setText("Dialog #" + mNum + ": using style "
            + getNameForNum(mNum));

    // Watch for button clicks.
    Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.show);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // When button is clicked, call up to owning activity.
            ((FragmentDialog)getActivity()).showDialog();
        }
    });

    return v;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragments` can be re-created at anytime by the system, and if the system needs to do it, it will call the default (no-args) constructor. Therefore, the only way to store the configuration of the fragment is through `setArguments`, which will store, serialize and unserialize the passed `Bundle` whenever the system needs to.
As [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) says:

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor.
>   The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed,
>   in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this
>   constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not
>   available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state
>   restore.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience I have figured out that when ever I try to create a constructor for a  Fragment it sais it can't be done. Thats becouse only default constructors need to be used in Fragments. 
I think that becouse DialogFragment is actualy a sort of fragment that's why it wont let you and you shouldnt use constructors to send data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary.  When you create a `DialogFragment`, just use the function `setArguments` to pass it a Bundle of arguments.

```
DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(value);
dialog.setArguments(args);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");
```